# What we mean by positive solution and radial solution of any  partial differential equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis

I am not getting the most of the article concern with the existence and uniqueness of positive solution and radial solution.
I just want to know how a positive solution and radial solution of nonlinear elliptic BVP can be described?

Comment: You need to be more specific if you  expect  a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without any further context, I suppose a positive solution is one that is greater than zero everywhere in the domain, i.e. for all $x$ it holds that $u(x) > 0$.

A radial solution might mean one that is only a function of the norm of the argument, i.e. for all $x$ it holds that $u(x) = u(\|x\|)$.